# htaccess で異なるドメインに内部転送したい

Tags: apache, .htaccess

以下の記述で内部転送したいのですが、ドメインが異なっているためリダイレクト扱いになってしまいます。これを解決するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

```
RewriteRule https://example1.jp/img/0001.jpg https://example2.jp/img/0001.jpg [L]
```

※example1が独自ドメイン
※example2がレンタルサーバーのドメイン
※置いてあるファイルは同サーバー
※詳しくは書いてませんが、フォルダ構造が微妙に違う
偽 `https://example2.jp/img/0001.jpg` →真 `https://example2.jp/test/img/0001.jpg`
このtestを隠したりしてるためhtaccessは必須

Comment: 別ドメインということはドキュメントルートは別ということですよね？ということはドキュメントルート外のファイルにmod_rewriteしたいというのが質問の本質でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

プロキシにしたいということですよね？
以下のように `[P]` フラグを使用します。
`RewriteRule` の第1引数は URL ではなくパスです。

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule img/0001.jpg https://example2.jp/test/img/0001.jpg [P,L]
```

ただし、HTTPS でプロキシ先(example2.jp)にアクセスするには、自サーバー(example1.jp)で `SSLProxyEngine on` を設定する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！